Importing off-chain data into TheGraph
graph-node from TheGraph can get data from blockchain.
I am reading Adding support for a new chain, which introduce how to use firehose to stream data to thegraph for new chain..
I wonder whether it is easy to update ingestor adpater to read offchain data from postgres assuming that there are chain data in pg.
Anyone can give some comments here? thanks

To my knowledge, the graph supports indexing IPFS and arweave, but not other external sources at this point in time. ref: https://thegraph.com/blog/file-data-sources-tutorial/
Another alternative is Envio, which could help your use case: https://docs.envio.dev/docs/async-mode
Can fetch data from any external source / API and add the data to pg db as part of indexing to pg db. Also can just index immediately using a RPC URL.
Here's an example of the implementation that fetches IPFS metadata and contract (token) info: ttps://github.com/wslyvh/show-up/tree/main/packages/indexer
